# C# WinForm application setup problem

Tags: c#

In my VS 2008 C# WinForm application, I've made the Install.msi and 
Setup.exe on my application release folder.

The client can install the application on C:\Program Files\ by running the setup.exe.

But there comes a new question, when I made a new Install.msi and Setup.exe,
the client has to remove the application via Control / Add Remove Program, 
then excute the Setup.exe.

How do we fix this problem so the client's update will be more convenient?

otherwise,

how to create simple exe file like vb exe.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do.  In the Properties for the Setup Project:

1. Set the RemovePreviousVersions property to TRUE.
2. Set the VersionNumber of the Setup Project.  When doing this, you will be prompted that you will need a new product code.  Just click Yes.

The VersionNumber of the installer is what the installer uses to determine if the current version is greater than the installed version.  If the current version is greater, it will uninstall the previous version, then install the new version.

Comment: @Eclipsed4utoo:Suppose,i have an exe to be install while installing my application.So, here i want to check whether my exe(filezilla.exe) is already installed or not(it may installed manually or using this setup).If it is already installed,no need to install my exe.Otherwise,Install it.Please guide me to get this issue...

Answer (score 2):

When you are deploying an update of your application with a VS2008 Setup Project, you must change the version of the project. 
When doing so, VS2008 will ask you that if you change the version of your application it will change the product code of your application. 
Mading these changes, when you will install the application on your client computer, Windows will detect that your application is an update of the older one and he will automatically overwrite the data with the new application data.

Hope it helps!
Regards,
PL